# Failed to mount Lock Directory and User Runtime Directory

Tags: filesystems, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian (debian). I tried [this](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=375201#p375201) and my system upgraded with no error. When I reboot, a surprise, my system does not turn on. I tried to search on the internet but nothing. This is the error:

[image]

(I can't even put a proper text log, I cannot access to my system.)

Please, what can I do?

EDIT: I SOLVED IT
I solved it! :)
I run

```
mountall.sh
mountall-bootclean.sh
```

that are in `/etc/init.d`

One of them said that I had to remove something in the `/etc/fstab` to complete the upgrade.
I commented the line with `/var/run` in `/etc/fstab`, rebooted and everything is fine.

Comment: What happens when you run  `systemctl status run-user.mount` ?

Comment: @Lawrence, same thing, Failed to get D-Bus connection: No connection to service manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! :)
I run

```
mountall.sh
mountall-bootclean.sh
```

that are in `/etc/init.d`

One of them said that I had to remove something in the `/etc/fstab` to complete the upgrade
I commented the line with `/var/run` in `/etc/fstab`, rebooted and everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try to find `run-lock.mount` in one of the standard paths:

- `/etc/systemd/system/run-lock.mount`
- `/run/systemd/generator/run-lock.mount`
- `/lib/systemd/system/run-lock.mount`
- `/usr/lib/systemd/system/run-lock.mount`

See if it's a bind mount or a regular tmpfs mount. If it's a bind mount, make sure the source directory exists; if it's tmpfs, make sure your kernel has tmpfs compiled in. *(Though if it didn't, then the boot process would have failed much earlier, when trying to mount `/run`...)*

Comment: It's in /lib/systemd/system/run-lock.mount 
It's a tmpfs filesystem
[Picture is here](http://it.tinypic.com/r/a43l0y/8)
Also in run-user.mount it says tmpfs

What should I do now?

Comment: @supermario3: Try to mount it manually?

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit? I'm not an expert. I tried "mount -o remount /run/lock" but it says it's not in fstab

Comment: @supermario3: `-o remount` does not make sense, as it's not mounted yet. Your screenshot shows "What=tmpfs", "Where=/run/lock", "Type=tmpfs", "Options=nodev,noexec,nosuid,size=5242880", and this translates to `mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /run/lock -o nodev,noexec,nosuid`.